# IO-Link Master implementation on FPGA

Tags: fpga, vhdl, io-link

I try to get a grasp on the IO-Link protocol but the [Interface Specification](https://io-link.com/share/Downloads/Spec-Interface/IOL-Interface-Spec_10002_V112_Jul13.pdf) seems to be horribly bad. 
Has someone ever used IO-Link on a FPGA? Is it feasable to implement a small master (I only have to support one specific sensor) or is the protocol to complex to have it in hardware? Do I really need all the different layers? The whole protocol is pretty blown up and I haven't found any reference project.

Comment: I guess there are MCUs already loaded with IO-link protocol stack. It is an industrial link, so you should be a member of the IO-Link Consortium, to make your own device.

Comment: I'm digging around https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-io-link.html#resource, its a C implementation. ST referes to teconcept, for the stack. You can buy industrial masters from say .. IFM or other vendors

Comment: Buying an existing master would be my backup plan, because I have an existing hardware platform which I'd like to directly connect to an IO Link sensor I thought there might be a possibility to implement a lightweight master in VHDL.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's still relevant, but: an IO-Link Master stack can be hardcoded just to read the sensor data/parameters. You would still need to read the spec or have experience with IO-Link to implement it but it's doable on an FPGA since basically it's just a serial protocol.